# I need a lot of questions for mathematics. Algebra to calculus so that I learn by solving.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, problem-solving

One huge problem I have with learning mathematics is that I have not got enough problems to solve, with answers. Is there a resource that I can get hundreds of mathematical questions, small questions, big questions all the way through from algebra to calculus that I can work my way through?

Comment: While I haven't used it, I've heard good things about [Brilliant](http://brilliant.org/)

Comment: @JasperLoy I'm trying to teach myself mathematics from algebra up to calculus. Hopefully that makes some sense, I want a resource that doesn't have gaps in the material going up to calculus

Comment: Buy a textbook.  Or, if you're a poor college student like me, "buy" a textbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out *[Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)* with notes and many worked examples on algebra, calculus, linear algebra and differential equations.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Schaum Series](http://www.mhprofessional.com/templates/index.php?cat=145). I didn't use it personally but I know people that liked it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Alcumus Learning System by Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Alcumus/Introduction.php) is very effective with problems ranging from Algebra to Number Theory. You can also do questions with [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) as well by first watching videos and then answering questions. For testing your guts out, try [Brilliant.org](http://brilliant.org).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using old textbooks, one of the things you can try is to google, in google-books (or also in google-web), the phrase "key to" along with various topics you're interested in. For example, look at the hits from these (title) searches: [key to trigonometry](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=intitle%3a%22key+to%22+intitle%3atrigonometry) ...... [key to calculus](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=intitle%3a%22key+to%22+intitle%3acalculus) ...... [key to algebra](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=intitle%3a%22key+to%22+intitle%3aalgebra). For those keys that you can download or view fully on-line, then google for the corresponding textbook (to get the problem statements; some keys include them and some don't).